# How to HTTP2 Request through Proxy in Golang

Tags: go, proxy, http2

I want to request to example.com over a proxy in HTTP2 library of Golang, can anyone please help me how to do it?
Thanks!

This example is for HTTP1 but i want this in HTTP2:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    var addressString = "https://www.example.com/"
    var proxyString = "http://127.0.0.1:9150"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", addressString, nil)
    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: func(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
            proxyURI, err := url.Parse(proxyString)
            return proxyURI, err
        },
    }

   // The http client is equipped to handle http/2 connections
    hc := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    resp, _ := hc.Do(req)
    log.Print(resp)
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong with the code that you have posted? Also post error messages. Ignoring the error in `hc.Do(req)` is not helpful; assign the error to a variable and print it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You are right it doesn't have any error, but it was just example of http1, i want to do it in http2

Comment: The Go http library will use http2 requests if the server supports it. What problem are you seeing when you use the above code with a proxy and a http2-supporting server?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The code works only if i dont edit DialTLS, when i want to use a spec tls it doesn't work anymore for http2. Could you please make me a request which use http2 using proxy and hellocustom?

Comment: Never mind i fixed it.